# Use pumping-lemma to prove that L is not a context-free language

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

Show using the pumping lemma that L = { $w$$w^{R}$$w$ | $w\in$ {a,b}* $w\notin$ *context-free language*  where $w^{R}$ denotes the reversed word $w$.

(if $w$ = $w_{1}$$w_{2}$$w_{3}$ ... $w_{n}$ ,$w^{R}$ = $w_{n}$$w_{n-1}$...$w_{2}$$w_{1}$

Use pumping lemma to prove that L is not a *context-free language*.

If the pump principle is used, how should it be constructed? I don’t know exactly how to solve it.

Comment: You are confusing context-free grammars and context-free languages. Please revise your question.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I have modified.

Comment: Hint: If you haven't seen any pumping-lemma problem solved, I'd take a look at the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages#Usage_of_the_lemma) in Wikipedia, or any question here in SE. Then, try to replicate this process with some particular easy-but-problematic word in this languge. For example, $b^p a^{2p} b^{2p} a^p$, try to make the same steps than in the example. If you try it and still you don't know how to finish, edit the question adding your own work.